# How to change the name of an Xcode file folder?

Tags: ios, xcode

(XCODE 5)
I may be wrong in calling it a file folder, but what I'm referring to is the folder that contains all the files that is created after making a new project. In my case, I saved my project onto the desktop, and originally named it something completely different. Now I want to change its name, but before when I changed the name of the folder it didn't work when I tried to build and run my app. The other question I had was how to move it to another location because same thing happened when I moved the project from the desktop.

I was also wondering what A or M or a ? mean beside the files on the left hand panel (inside the project)

Comment: I was wondering the same thing about the renaming part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of renaming the folder, you're generally fine renaming the top level folder, but it can get messy when renaming one of its one of the subfolders. If you rename the subfolders, side affects include (a) messing up links in the Xcode project; and (b) if you're using version control, losing the connection between the previous change history and the new file. But if you're talking about the top level folder under which everything for the project is included, I've never had problems renaming that.

In terms of the A/M designation, a A means that new file has been added to the project; M means that an existing file has been modified. You'll only see these when your project is under version control (which is a checkbox you can check when creating your project.)